# Ninject 3.0 and MVC4 Generic Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I've got an MVC 4 application that I want to use Ninject with. I've used NuGet for the Ninject 3 packages, however I'm having some difficulties with the configuration. The NuGet install created the file:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
     // Not included for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {

    }
}
```

I have a class I'm using to strongly type my web config. I've called this class AppEnvironment, and it has an interface of IAppEnvironment for unit testing. I know that within the RegisterSevices function I can do:

```
kernel.Bind<IAppEnvironment>().To<AppEnvironment>();
```

However this means that I have to specify each binding one at a time. In a previous project we had Ninject configured to bind by default to a new instance of the interface with just the I of the interface class removed. I've taken a look at [Using NInject to bind a generic interface, with a default if a binding for the generic type is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066692/using-ninject-to-bind-a-generic-interface-with-a-default-if-a-binding-for-the-g) however I'm not sure what the IService in `.InheritedFrom(typeof(IService<>))` is for, and what I should be using for my configuration.

Any clues on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InheritedFrom(typeof(IService<>))` filters the types returned by `SelectAllClasses()` (all the types in the assembly) to include only the types that are `IService<Something>`.

In you scenario you might use the convention extensions and do:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .BindDefaultInterface());
```

`BindDefaultInterface` assumes the naming convention that you described (which is common): e.g. `Foo` is bound to `IFoo`.

Comment: I actually just figured this out myself (often the way of it). I also had a second issue that was confusing things. The interface and class were in a separate project and so weren't being picked up by `FromThisAssembly` I had to do `FromAssembliesMatching`.